# Windows Azure geo-location

Tags: security, geolocation, azure, location

I’m doing some research into the capabilities of Windows Azure for an European company. One of their concerns is that data will be processed/stored by servers in the USA. (Regarding the patriot act)

Microsoft does provide the option to select a geo-location, but I have yet to find them guaranteeing that the data won’t be processed or stored in the USA. Besides that there aren’t any geo-locations available outside of the USA (heard there will be once the CTP is over).

So, I wonder how Microsoft will handle this. I’m sure more companies in Europe have the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose a region for your Windows Azure application, we never move your compute/storage outside that region.  (We should make this clearer in the documentation.)

As you mentioned, stay tuned to PDC (just two weeks away!) to hear about new locations.

Comment: Not sure where this is explicitly called out; we'll make sure it is.